# Efficient dominating set using branching

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, exponential, np, branching-strategy

Exact dominating set is a dominating set in which exactly one element of N[v] belongs to dominating set.I have used branching to find a solution.if a vertex v is selected then N[v] is deleted and N^2(v) is colored blue.I am not sure if my solution is correct I am attaching  my solution [solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14mqSGVapJ5PqMh5ccnh11a1Lri7iK8N3/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Could you edit your question to be a bit more self contained (or a link to the dominating set methematical description) and clarify what is your actual question please?

Comment: Please provide more information for the concept you are describing

Comment: Yeah it's called efficient  dominating set